# context.fillText and context.fillRect not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I had no idea why it won't works, same methods used in other code which works but not this one, there's no errors and warnings at the console too, is there any wrong in my code?

[Code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckup5w1x/)

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// styling
canvas.style.position = "absolute";

canvas.height = 300;

canvas.width = 500;

canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.left = "0px";

var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");

// title should be larger
cxt.font = "15px arial";

cxt.textAlign = "center";

cxt.fillStyle = "black";

cxt.fillText(
    "Testing Chart",
    250,
    200
);

cxt.fillRect(
    250,
    200,
    50,
    50
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `document.getElementById("chart").appendChild(canvas);`. You forgot to add canvas to document.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in my other code which the canvas already appended into child of specific parent element which already the element also visible in browser and I also call `cxt.fillText` and `cxt.fillRect` after the canvas has been appended.

Comment: Just found the solution just now and it's not related to the code I inserted above.